# Django form not showing errors but redisplays new form

Tags: django

I have a Insert view  which displays model data from one primary and one related model. Once finished displaying the data a form is appended to the table to add a new related item.

This works fine - however if I enter invalid data (like a invalid time to be exact), and hit one of the submit buttons, it simply refreshes the page with a blank entry form for the related data again.  It doesn't display the data I entered, and it doesn't display an error message even though the form includes the error fields.

I have tried adding form_invalid to my CBV and calling the form but I can see that it just calls the InserView again with no context (which basically does the get_context_data call again and give me a new blank form).

How do I get it to put up the form with my data from before and the errors as well.
See code below:

```
views.py

class SegmentAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
  login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  model = Segment
  template_name = 'segment_add_view.html'
  form_class = SegmentForm

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SegmentAddView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    program_info = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context['program_info'] = program_info
    last_segment = program_info.segments.last()
    if last_segment:
      add_sequence_num = last_segment.sequence_number + Decimal(1.00)
    else: 
      add_sequence_num = Decimal(1.00)
    context['form'] = SegmentForm(initial={'sequence_number': add_sequence_num})       
    return context

  def form_valid(self, form):
    program = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    form.instance.program = program
    return super().form_valid(form)

  def form_invalid(self, form):
    print(" Inside form invalid")
    return super(SegmentAddView, self).form_invalid(form)

  def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    print(" Inmside Success")
    altered_program = Program.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    altered_program.save()

    if 'save_another' in self.request.POST:
        return reverse_lazy('segment_add', args=[self.kwargs['pk']])
    return reverse_lazy('program_detail', args=[self.kwargs['pk']])
           
forms.py

class SegmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
          
  class Meta:
    model = Segment
    exclude = ('seg_length_time_delta',
        'seg_run_time',
        'seg_run_time_delta'   ,
        'seg_remaining_time',
        'seg_remaining_time_delta',
        'program',
        'audit_user',
    )     
          
  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.audit_user = self.request.username
    #request.user.username
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Template looks like:

```
<TABLE ID="pro-table" WIDTH="100%">
      <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
        <TD ALIGN="Center" WIDTH="35">&nbsp;#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Segment Title</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Summary</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Library</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Author</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Voice</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Segment time</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Center">Run time</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Center">Rem. time</TD>
      </TR>
      {% if program_info.segments.all %}
        {% for segments in program_info.segments.all %}
          <tr BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="35">{{ segments.sequence_number }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.title|default_if_none:'No Title'  }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top"><PRE>{{ segments.summary|truncatechars:40 }}</PRE></TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.library }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.author|default_if_none:'' }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.voice|default_if_none:'' }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ segments.seg_length_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ segments.seg_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            {% if segments.seg_run_time_delta > program_info.block_time_delta %}
              <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="TOP" Width="10">&nbsp;(-{{ segments.seg_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})</TD>
            {% else %}
              <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="TOP" Width="10">&nbsp;{{ segments.seg_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            {% endif %}
          </TR>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="35">{{ form.sequence_number }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.title }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top"><PRE>{{ form.summary }}</PRE></TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.library }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.author }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.voice }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ form.seg_length_time }}</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
          <TD Align="Left" VALIGN="Top">Bridge:&nbsp;{{ form.bridge_flag }}</TD>
          <TD></TD> <TD></TD> <TD></TD> <TD></TD> <TD></TD> <TD></TD>
        </TR>
        {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
           {% for error in field.errors %}
               <p> {{ errors }} </p>
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <p> {{ error }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <TR>
          <td> <a href="{% url 'program_detail' program_info.pk %}">
        Lose Edits</a></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="save_only" Value="Save-View Program"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="save_another" Value="Save-Add Another"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </TABLE>
```

I originally had a slightly different error display - but I changed it to this eror block just to see if I could get anything output to no avail.

How do I call the form with the context of the errors that happened? Not quite sure how to do that correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track - but was missing the right context values.

The solution:

Inside my views.py - needed to add the previous form to the context when invalid and then render it.

```
def form_invalid(self, form , **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = form
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```